# How to get Dow Jones Index (DJI) data from Google?

Tags: r, quantmod

I am trying to get the data for the Dow Jones Index from google.
I have tried a number of things but they do not seem to work.

```
require(quantmod)
getSymbols(".DJI",src = "google")
getSymbols("^DJI",src = "google")
getSymbols("INDEXDJX:.DJI",src = "google")
```

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to get price data from Google finance?  Have you found it to be superior to Yahoo finance in any way?

Comment: Yahoo Finance is great. I just was trying to get it to work with google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is "HTTP: 404 Not Found". That means the page `getSymbols` uses doesn't exist for the Dow Jones Index (it also does not exist for the S&P500 and the Nasdaq Composite). There's nothing quantmod can do if Google doesn't provide the data...